# Void** Confusion for callbacks

Tags: c, callback, glib, void-pointers

I am working with a open source mapping tool and it has the ability to use g_io_add_watch to watch file descriptors. I am trying to watch the stdin file descriptor and I have successfully be able to have the callback be called when the stdin recieves data. I am not able to read this data however. I am trying to modify the callback to recieve the infromation described int the handler for the open source api.

EDIT** My question is first off what is a void** and how would it be used in this case. I want my call back function to be provided the parameters that are described for the readUserInput_two function you see below, and I need to pass it through the callback system described below. I am confused as to what I would need to pass as my void** to allow the current implementation to pass those parameters.

It looks like this

```
readUserInput_two(GIOChannel *ioch, GIOCondition cond, gpointer data)
```

I want to store this pointer into the callback which is defined as

```
struct callback {
    void (*func)();
    int pcount;
    enum attr_type type;
    void *p[0];

};
```

In the function that is used to instantiate a callback you provide the following parameters

```
callback_new(void (*func)(void), int pcount, void **p)
```

In this call pcount is the number of parameters your function pointer should have, and i believe void**p is either the type of those parameters or something of the sort but I cant seem to figure it out.

When the callback is fired it calls a function defined in a define statement that looks as such.

```
#define callback_call_3(cb,p1,p2,p3) callback_call_args(cb, 3, p1, p2, p3)
```

This function is defined for a variety of number of p's ex. callback_call_1(cb,p1) also exists. Can anyone explain how I might go about getting my callback function to recieve those data fields. the intermediate callback fire function that calls callback_call_3 looks like this .

```
static gboolean
navfocus_call_watch(GIOChannel * iochan, GIOCondition condition, gpointer t)
{
    struct callback *cb=t;
    if(cb->pcount == 1)//I added this if before it only had callback_call_0
    {
        callback_call_0(cb);
    }
    else if(cb->pcount == 4)
    {
        callback_call_3(cb,iochan,condition,t);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your question, what did you try, what does not work??

Answer (score 2):

void** is a pointer to pointer of a void type data (no type). void* is used as a generic type to point to the base address of any type variable. In this case, the void** expects to hold multiple void* variables. You can call it as void array.

There are various functions to be called which are based on the number of parameters sent from the callback_new(). There are macros written for convenience.

You need to embed those parameters into void** p. You can allocate the memory for the void** p array as follows:

```
void **p = malloc(10 * sizeof *p);
```

You need to embed them in the same order required by the final function that is called.

Say for 3 parameter function:

```
p[0] = &iochan;
p[1] = &condition;
p[2] = &t;
```

Now send the void** p to callback_new(theFunctionPointer, 3, p); and as you explained, appropriate function will be called based on number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

A `void**` is a type for a pointer to a pointer to void.

As to how to use it in your case, you'll have to consult the documentation. I can't tell from the snippet of code you posted and a variable name of "p" doens't really help either.

Edit: As to your call back being provided your original data, the callback function doesn't have any arguments. How does the function get your pointer?

Edit2: I see, it's to do with pcount. But then the declaration of the callback is wrong as it states that the callback does not take any arguments...